# How to color the exterior of a region in a `RegionPlot`?

Tags: plotting, regions

One can color the interior of a region by `ColorFunction`. But how to color the exterior of a region of a `RegionPlot` (I want to change the standard white color to lets say red)? Whats the necessary command?

btw: `Background` is actually not what I'm looking for, as it colors the background even outside the `PlotRegion`!

Comment: ...but the white color is precisely the background! If you must have a different colorization without involving the background, make another `RegionPlot[]`, this time of the negation of the original region function.

Comment: ...a pitty. Negation was my primary idea too. However, applying a `BoundaryStyle` causes some troubles in my actual code than.

Comment: @J.M. so you are saying: it is not possible to adress both, interior and exterior of a region within `RegionPlot` ?

Comment: As far as `RegionPlot[]` is concerned, it will only generate primitives corresponding to points that satisfy the region function given, and nothing more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As JM suggested, you can plot the complement of the region you are interested in, and assign a color to that:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 + y^2 <= 2, x^2 + y^2 > 2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the complement of your region cannot be readily expressed, or more in general for multiple regions, you can identify *the plane* as a region where (x,y) are real:

```
RegionPlot[{
   {x, y} ∈ Reals, 
   x^2 + y^2 < 3},
   {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Opacity[1]]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]